# How to validate multi-row forms in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to validate multirow forms in laravel. I would like to validate a form which looks like this:

```
<input name="address[]" class="addr"/>
<input name="address[]" class="addr"/>
```

I've tried both methods but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$rule = array('address[]' => 'required'); //still returning error even if all required fields are filled up 
$rule = array('address' => 'required'); //nothing happens
```

For the first one I made sure that there is no hidden address field:

```
$('.addr').length
```

The length returned is equal to the number of address fields I have filled out

Comment: Is it possible that you already asked this question at the Laravel forums a few minutes ago? Have a little patience :)

Comment: @Franz I am stuck with this too. What happens if i use something like <input name="something[]id" /> and <input name="something[]name" />

Comment: @Murat: I would assume that is not valid HTML.

Comment: @Franz Oh my bad. <input name="something[][id]" /> This is the one i was using. Sorry

Comment: Hmm, I would assume it automatically create increasing indices. Just try it out. To be on the safe side, just use `[0]` for both id and name.

Comment: Oh i got it. Btw, regarding to the main question on the top, i know that Laravel can use dots for validation like address.id or address.name when <input name="address[name]" /> How may i use validations for <input name="something[][id]" /> ? Do i need to extend my validations?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use either of these:

```
$rule = array('address' => 'array'); 
$rule = array('address' => 'countmin:0');
```

Comment: thanks but this doesn't seem to work, both has no effect, like the rule wasn't even there

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using?

Comment: I think its version 3, or whatever is available on laravel.com/download

Comment: If you use git, you should clone laravel as submodule into your project and point laravel system folder from path.php. Thus you won't end up replacing files every time when laravel is updated

Answer (score 1):

I just extended the validator class and created a simple rule that checks if there's an empty value in the array:

```
public function validate_arrayfull($attribute, $value, $parameters){
        $is_full = (in_array('', $value)) ? false : true;
        return $is_full;
    }
```

And in Validation.php a default error message:

```
"arrayfull"      => "The :attribute contains empty values"
```

Usage:

```
$rule = array('address' => 'arrayfull');
```